# Problem with import in latest version of Drools

Tags: java, drools, rules

I'm new to Drools and I'm trying to start using different tutorials. Lately I've started those two: https://koziolekweb.pl/2008/10/30/jboss-rules-drools-silnik-regul-biznesowych/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQhDe_PT60Y but they're using older Drools and I'm using version 7.62.Final. My errors are within those imports:

```
import org.drools.RuleBase;
import org.drools.RuleBaseFactory;
import org.drools.StatefulSession;
import org.drools.StatelessSession;
import org.drools.compiler.DroolsParserException;
import org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder;
import org.drools.rule.Package;
```

and

```
import org.drools.StatefulSession;
```

Have they changed in new version of Drools? How may I change them in the code while using for example PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder(); etc? And where can I find this information if it's available?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those tutorials are written against a very old version of Drools (probably Drools 4 or 5, based on the publish date.) Between Drools 5 and 6 there was effectively a complete rewrite, so the backend of the Drools library is completely different.

The imports you mention no longer exist. They no longer exist because their *concepts* have fundamentally changed. In Drools 5, we had Rule Bases. In Drools 7, we have Kie Bases. Configurations, defaults, how you load and fire rules ... everything is different. If you want to follow those tutorials, down-rev to Drools 5 ... but you can't go to 6.x or newer.

Your best bet is to completely ignore the tutorials -- which are worthless -- and just read the documentation. The Drools documentation is actually very good, and very in depth. Otherwise if you insist on reading tutorials, make sure that you find tutorials targeting 7 (and the newer version of Drools 7 the better, because after 7.44 or so they started implementing non-backwards compatible changes in minor releases.)

Answer (score 0):

Latest from drools is v7.x. I followed the drools examples from the official repository. Check the examples from https://github.com/kiegroup/drools.git
And make sure you switch to latest branch example 'r7.73.0.Final'

Refer the official documentation. I found it a bit overwhelming to understand it initially.
https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html

Answer (score -1):

If you build is complaining that it is not finding these imports the real problem is likely that you do not have the correct maven dependencies in your pom.xml downloaded; I am sure that DROOLS still uses the StatelessSession, StatefulSession, etc.

There are two ways to update your pom.xml to use the correct dependency.  Do a search on Google

```
maven org.drools.StatelessSession
```

and the first item returned is jar.download.com - which let's you download the JAR containing the StatelessSession class for a specific version of the tool.  The sixth entry returned by the search is for https://mvnrepository.com - where these JARs are officially stored - showing you the pom.xml dependency for a specific version.  Either way, you should make sure you get the correct version of the JAR specified in the pom.xml or downloaded.

DROOLS, JBPM, KIE, etc. use a BOM (bill of materials) project to specify the version of dependencies across a technology (i.e., so if there are 8 hibernate dependencies all 8 reflect the same version.)  Your DROOLS documentation probably lists these versions or has a link to the BOM.

Comment: Thank you, and to which folder should I paste this Jar file? I've always have problems with this as I never know which kind of drools should I download and all of them have different folders structure. Thank you in advance

Comment: And maybe one more question. What is a dependency between folders in which you have a drools project and drools downloaded. For example I have my projects in users/me/eclipse_workspaces and drools in users/me/drools/droolsjbpm-integration-distribution-7.62.0.Final. Should they be in same directory or it's enough if I add run path in eclipse to drools destination? Sorry for question but I'm a complete novice.

Comment: @adelaida If I am understanding the questions correctly, in the latter directory - the first is simply your project within Eclipse.  The latter is the actual DROOLS libraries.  I would be surprised to not find these classes in the latter directory and wonder if your pom.xml is wrong (which is used to specify which libraries to use - at the project level - so they can be imported.)

Answer (score -1):

One of the blog you are referring is very old and after that there huge amount of changes in the dependencies. You should try updating your pom.xml file and Java Code accordingly. You can download required dependencies from https://mvnrepository.com/

Can you attach you project here ?